# Spring configuration file doesn't execute constructor

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have noticed the constructor is not been executed when injecting the configuration class in another class. Hence it failing with null pointer exception for mac.  Do i need to create using `@Bean` for `mac, secretKeySpec`?

```
 @Component
public class S3Configuration {

         @Value("${" + AWS_ACCESS_KEY + "}")
            private String awsAccessKey;
        @Value("${" + AWS_SECRET_KEY + "}")
        private String awsSecretKey;
        @Value("${" + AWS_BUCKET_NAME + "}")
        private String awsBucketName;
        @Value("${" + AWS_ENDPOINT + "}")
        private String awsEndpoint;

        public S3Configuration(){
            try {
                byte [] secretKeyBytes = awsAccessKey.getBytes(UTF8_CHARSET);
                secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKeyBytes, HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM);
                mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM);
                mac.init(secretKeySpec);
            } catch(Exception e){

            }

        }
        public String sign(Map<String, String> params, String filename){
            params.put("AWSAccessKeyId", awsSecretKey);
            params.put("Timestamp", timestamp());
            String canonicalizedResource = "/" + awsBucketName + "/" + filename;
            SortedMap<String, String> sortedParamMap = new TreeMap<String, String>(params);
            String canonicalQS = canonicalize(sortedParamMap);
            String toSign = 
                    REQUEST_METHOD + "\n"
                            + awsEndpoint + "\n"
                            + canonicalizedResource + "\n"
                            + canonicalQS;
            String hmac = hmac(toSign);
            String sig = percentEncodeRfc3986(hmac);
            String url = "http://" + awsEndpoint + canonicalizedResource + "?"+canonicalQS + "&Signature=" + sig;
            return url;
        }

private String hmac(String stringToSign){
    String signature = null;
    byte[] data;
    byte[] rawHmac;
    try {
        data = stringToSign.getBytes(UTF8_CHARSET);
        rawHmac = mac.doFinal(data);
          signature = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(rawHmac));
    } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        throw new RuntimeException(UTF8_CHARSET + " is unsupported!", e);
    }
    return signature;
}
...
}
```

### Calling from different class

```
@Component
@Resource
public AssetResouce {
    @Autowired
    public AssetResource( final S3Configuration s3configuration) {
        this.s3configuration = s3configuration;
    }
```

in one of the method i call signParams from s3configuration

```
params = s3configuration.signParams(params, assetId);
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not executing the constructor and getting an exception somewhere? Add an `e.printStackTrace()` inside the catch and check, please.

Comment: It is not going inside the constructor and hence mac is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Class with the @Configuration annotation is equivalent to a xml config file, you are doing bad use of it.

Please check the documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/

Comment: I will replace it with @component will that fix it?

Comment: Please check this example: http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-javaconfig-example/ you must crate an application context.